# Redirect to different component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
navigateToMyComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:myComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:myComponent",
        componentAttributes: {
            recordId : recId
        }
    });
    evt.fire();
},
```

I am using above function to navigate one component to another but getting the below error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Action failed: c:test$controller$navigateToMyComponent [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
>   Failing descriptor: {c:test$controller$navigateToMyComponent}

Comment: Are you trying in lightning application (.app) ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be getting a reference to the `force:navigateToComponent` event - and you pass it the name of the component you want to navigate to. Eg:

```
navigateToMyComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:myComponent",
        componentAttributes: {
            recordId : recId
        }
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```

Essentially, you need to fix line 3 of your code:

```
var evt = $A.get("e.force:myComponent");
```

Should be:

```
var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you. I have used the same in my developer org and it works fine.

https://force-base.com/2016/01/04/how-to-navigate-from-one-component-to-another-in-lightning/